# CodeSignal isLucky task c++

Tags: c++

Started to practice C++ by trying to do some tasks in CodeSignal, but I can’t figure it out why it has an output which is always false. Saw a similar answer to this task but didn’t want to copy and paste without understanding where the error is.

*Ticket numbers usually consist of an even number of digits. A ticket number is considered lucky if the sum of the first half of the digits is equal to the sum of the second half.*

Example:

```
For n = 1230, the output should be isLucky(n) = true

For n = 239017, the output should be isLucky(n) = false
```

Code:

```
 bool isLucky(int n) {
    
   string convert = to_string(n); // to convert from string to int
   
   int sizehalbe = convert.size() / 2; //divide into 2 halfs
   
   //Stor each half
   string h1 = convert.substr(0, sizehalbe-1);
   string h2 = convert.substr(sizehalbe, convert.size()-1);
   
   int sum1=0, sum2=0; //Calculate the halfs
   
   
   for(int i=0;i<h1.length();i++)
   { 
       sum1 += int(h1.at(i));
   }
   
    for(int j=0;j<h2.length();j++)
   { 
       sum2 += int(h2.at(j));
   }
  
 
   if(sum1 == sum2)
        return true;
   else
        return false;  
}
```

Comment: You have two comments in the code, none are correct.  Especially the second one is one you should note, as it says you do something which you *should* do, but doesn't.

Comment: Also, this is the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. If you did that then you should have discovered the problems very quickly.

Comment: Regarding the edits you just made, is it to fix a simple typo in the code you show on this site, or to fix an actual problem in the actual code? If it's the former then you should always copy-paste code, not rewrite as that can introduce unrelated problems. If it's the latter then don't do such edits to "fix" the code as then your question becomes worthless.

Comment: Notice than `'0' != 0`, even if in your case the offset doesn't bothers as `h1.size() == hs.size()`.

Comment: Hey @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for the answer, I copy - pasted the code from the site and saw that by pasting it here I accidently typed //2 instead of /2 for the Division. I also initialized the sum1 and sum2 , and no, I’m not used to debugging because I’m very new to programming, but I’ll try!

Comment: I suggest to print `h1` and `h2` (or see their values in debugger). You should then spot the issue and the fix immediately.

Answer (score 0):

(1). Foremost your h1 always miss one digit so instead of
`h1 = convert.substr(0, sizehalbe-1);`

that's the only main issue your code has, `convert` should be gone till `sizehalbe`

> `string h1 = convert.substr(0, sizehalbe);`

---

(2). whenever you typecast from character to integer, check what it gives
`cout<<int('0');` will give you `48` instead of `0`.

in particular, this case it's not changed your main output
(due to both sum1 & sum2 will get higher result than what actually should be,
but get same level of higher.)

> `sum½ += int(h½.at(i)) - 48;`

---

(3). you can optimize your last condition.
when boolean result is depending on condition you can do

> `return (sum1 == sum2);`